# Working with nested vectors

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault, grid-layout

I'm having some problems with a segmentation fault, and I think I know what the problem is, but I'm not really sure how to fix it

I have a grid as such

```
    class Grid {
      std::vector<std::vector<Cell>> grid;
      ...
    };
```

and I have a bunch of member functions working with that grid. One of my functions is the initialize function

```
    void Grid::init(int n) { 
      gridSize=n;
      vector<vector<Cell>> theGrid(n+1, vector<Cell>(n+1));
      for(int r=0; r<n; ++r) {
        for(int c=0; c<n; ++c) {
          theGrid[r][n] = Cell();
          theGrid[r][n].setCoords(r,c);
          theGrid[r].push_back(theGrid[r][c]);
       }
     }
```

However, once I initialize the grid, I was under the impression that I could call theGrid[x][y] in my other member functions and I would get the same one I initialized here as long as I was calling the methods on the same object. Whenever I try to access theGrid in my other member functions to do stuff with them, I get a segmentation fault unless I include

```
       vector<vector<Cell>> theGrid(n+1, vector<Cell>(n+1));
```

and that will basically mean I'm not working with the grid I want. How do I fix the problem? I want to be able to use the grid I initialized in my init in other methods. Any input would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is the (private) member of your class `grid` or `theGrid`? What are you trying to do with `theGrid[r].push_back(theGrid[r][c]);`?

Comment: its called `theGrid`. I think I was trying to append the Cell at coordinate (r,c) into the nested vector, and looking back on it, that code doesn't really make sense since I already assumed that theGrid[r][c] exists

Answer (score 1):

In your `init` function you declare:

```
vector<vector<Cell>> theGrid(n+1, vector<Cell>(n+1));
```

I don't know the reason of the `n+1` dimension, but as a matter of fact, you are declaring a **local** variable named `theGrid`, which may have or not the same name of the private member of your class (in the code posted that one is called `grid`), but surely its scope is limited to the `init` function.
That's the reason why you have to redeclare it in all the other function to avoid the segmentation fault.

The real fix should be to use in all the member functions the exact same name of the member variable of the class, **without** redeclaring it every time.

You can set the size of the vector of vector (which is a bad idea on its own, try using a 1D vector and index it doing v(i * width + j) instead of v[i][j]) in the constructor of your class or [resize](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) it in `init`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to ensure that the vectors are all of the correct length after calling `init()`, you can achieve this by calling [std::vector::resize()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize):

```
void Grid::init(int n)
{
    theGrid.resize(n);

    for(decltype(theGrid)::size_type rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < n; ++rowIndex))
    {
        auto& row = theGrid[rowIndex];
        row.resize(n);
        for(decltype(row)::size_type colIndex = 0; colIndex < n; ++colIndex)
        {
            auto& cell = row[colIndex];
            cell.setCoords(rowIndex, colIndex);
        }
    }
}
```